# Laravel obtain the selected value from a Form::Select

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I have an array with name `$crit` where I put the value of my HTML form components
for example this input:

```
{{ Form::label('name', 'Name:', array('class'=>'label'))}}
{{ Form::text('name', isset($criteria['name'])?$crit['name']:'', array('id'=>'name', 'class'=>'input'))}}<br/>
```

I want to do the same with the select component but I don't know how to add the value of the selected sex to my `$crit` array.

```
{{Form::label('Sex', 'Sex:', array('class'=>'label'))}}
{{Form::select('sex', $options, 'M', array('id'=>'sex'))}}
```

On my view I have defined the array `$options`

```
public function get_index()
{
    return View::make('personal.data')
    ->with('options', array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female'))
}
```

Thanks for your answer, Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use `Input::old` and it'll be re-populated on redirect/error

```
{{ Form::select('sex', $options, Input::old('sex')) }}
```