# Undefined variable Laravel

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, laravel

I'm trying to make  a dropdown list but the code don't recognize the array($comunas), telling that's a undefined variable

This is the controller

```
class ComunasController extends BaseController {

public function mostrarComunas()
{
    $comunas = Comuna::all();
    return View::make('pymes.crear', array('comunas' => $comunas));
}
```

The route

```
Route::get('pymes/crear', array('uses' => 'ComunasController@mostrarComunas'));
```

The View

```
{{Form::select('Comuna', $comunas->Nombre_Comuna, $comunas->Id_Comuna)}}
```

Comment: Seems like your treating a collection of models as an object. That should be an array of objects.

Comment: If you only want a single model object of `Comuna` then change `$comunas = Comuna::all();` to `$comunas = Comuna::first();`

Comment: @Jono20201 changing to $comunas = Comuna::first(); keep saying Undefined Variable

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
$comunas = Comuna::lists('Nombre_Comuna', 'Id_Comuna');
return View::make('pymes.crear', array('comunas' => $comunas));
```

In the `view`:

```
{{ Form::select('Comunas', $comunas, Input::old('Comunas')) }}
```

Comment: What didn't work ? Do you have `Nombre_Comuna` and `Id_Comuna` in your table, what columns it contains exactly ? It should work anyways! [Check the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/html#drop-down-lists).

Comment: [Check similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21438720/laravel-obtain-the-selected-value-from-a-formselect/21440992#21440992).

Comment: keep saying that $comunas is an Undefined Variable

Comment: I've passed `array('comunas' => $comunas)` from the `controller` to the `view` and in the view used `$comunas` so there is no way to tell that it is undefined because array key `comunas` is used.

Comment: Make sure you didn't make any mistakes.

Comment: i'm sure that i didn't make any mistake, you can see in my code, that everything is not mistyped, but it keeps saying undefined, i will keep searching if i found something i'll post it